# How to preserve consistency of string passed by asp.net into stored procedure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[XY]
    @FILTER NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
    BEGIN
...
...
```

Therefore, this procedure expects one parameter at most - right?

Let's consider this ASP.NET code now:

```
using (MainContext ctx = new MainContext())
{
    var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = 'XY';
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    if (param_list != null && param_list.Count > 0)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(param_list.ToArray());
    }

    try
    {
        // Run the stored procedure
        ctx.Database.Connection.Open();
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        p_Entity01 = 
            ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext.Translate<TEntity01>(reader).ToList();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        ctx.Database.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Assuming 'param_list' contain one string 'čefer'. When my procedure XY run with given parameter 'param_list', then @FILTER should be equal 'čefer' right ?

But nothing happened as expected. @FILTER = 'cefer' instead.

When I run XY procedure with explicitly declared variable @FILTER NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'čefer' then @FILTER = 'cefer'.

If I try @FILTER NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'čefer' then @FILTER = 'čefer', that's what I want.

But, this string is passed to procedure by asp.net.

I tried format (i.e. "N'čefer") given string in asp.net before calling procedure.

This story happens also with 'Ď'. Š,Ž.. works fine so I don't see the pattern according to which some letters works and others not.

Do you have any experiences with this please ?

Thank you

**EDIT**

The `param_list` is set up like this

```
Param = new SqlParameter("@FILTER", DbType.String)
    { Value = searchCriteria.TrimEnd(new char[] { ';' }) };
param_list.Add(Param);
```

Comment: Unrelated tips. Don't ever `throw e;` where `e` is the exception that you've caught. You will lose the stack trace. To re-throw the exception just use `throw;`. Also `reader` is disposable, so should be in a `using` block.

Comment: what is `param_list` and how did you populate it? also: is this "ent lib"? that tool is *ancient*, and it isn't exactly friendly by modern standards... there are tools that are *much* easier to work with these days...

Comment: @Richardissimo My question is about, how to format given string correctly on db. side, please.

Comment: @MarcGravell             
Param = new SqlParameter("@FILTER", DbType.String) { Value = searchCriteria.TrimEnd(new char[] { ';' }) };
param_list.Add(Param);
My problem is, i got this code, and have to solve this bug. :{

Comment: @Ashkops well, `DbType.String` is *correct* for unicode, and `@FILTER NVARCHAR` is correct. Something *somewhere* is treating it as `varchar` (not `nvarchar`), but: we can't tell you what. Check the SP, and check the table definition - make sure everything has `nvarchar`

Comment: @MarcGravell yea, string is broken since declaration part FILTER NVARCHAR= NULL. So I rly don't know how can it be done as varchar. Maybe it's db settings problem ?

Comment: @Ashkops again, I would be checking all the TSQL variables in the proc, and all column definitions (including temp tables and table variables in TSQL); something somewhere isn't nvarchar

Comment: @Ashkops I fully understand that. That's why I posted a comment rather than an answer, and it's why I prefixed it by saying "unrelated tips". At the time of writing this, two other people felt it was helpful of me to point this out to you. Welcome to the site - we try to be helpful. Another tip would be that if you need to add some important information to your question, you should [edit] your question rather than put it in comments. I will do that for your explanation of how you are setting up the parameters, because that's important.

Comment: Are you sure you don't need `SqlDbType.NVarChar` instead of `DbType.String`? I [do not see a constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.sqlparameter.aspx) accepting a DbType

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I have tried passing nvarchar into given asp method :{. I am pretty sure that problem is in declaration part in procedure. Collation of db is also right.